# Values from php form to javascript form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

first of all sorry for my English. :/  I'll try to be clear. :)

I'm using a CMS and I have two different forms (by two different plugins):

1. Form in PHP (plugin for registration users);
2. Form in JavaScript (plugin for a booking system).

I need to get (or post) values from php form to javascript form if these values already exist.

So, example:

1. An user goes to "register" page and sets his data in every field (in php form);
2. After this user goes to "booking" page, where there is another form (js) with the same fields of the first form and new fields to set: **he hasn't to repeat the data in the same fields, they should be printed (echo) automatically.**

This is form 1 (PHP), only 3 fields:
[image: PHP]

And this is form 2 (JavaScript), that repeats the 3 fields and contains new fields. I would to echo the values of those fields automatically:
[image: JS]

Code PHP Register Form (1):

```
<form name="registerform" id="registerform<?php $template->the_instance(); ?>" action="<?php $template->the_action_url( 'register' ); ?>" method="post">

    <p> <label for="iCountry<?php $template->the_instance(); ?>"><?php _e( 'Select Your Country', 'theme-my-login' ) ?></label> <select name="iCountry" id="iCountry<?php $template->the_instance(); ?>" class="input"><option value="IT">Italy</option><option value="US">USA</option><option value="DE">Germany</option></select>    </p>

    <p>         <label for="user_login<?php $template->the_instance(); ?>"><?php _e( 'First Name' ); ?></label>         <input type="text" name="user_login" id="user_login<?php $template->the_instance(); ?>" class="input" value="<?php $template->the_posted_value( 'user_login' ); ?>" size="20" />    </p>

    <p>         <label for="user_email<?php $template->the_instance(); ?>"><?php _e( 'E-mail' ); ?></label>         <input type="text" name="user_email" id="user_email<?php $template->the_instance(); ?>" class="input" value="<?php $template->the_posted_value( 'user_email' ); ?>" size="20" />    </p>

    <?php do_action( 'register_form' ); ?>

    <p id="reg_passmail<?php $template->the_instance(); ?>"><?php echo apply_filters( 'tml_register_passmail_template_message', __( 'A password will be e-mailed to you.' ) ); ?></p>

    <p class="submit">      <input type="submit" name="wp-submit" id="wp-submit<?php $template->the_instance(); ?>" value="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Register' ); ?>" />       <input type="hidden" name="redirect_to" value="<?php $template->the_redirect_url( 'register' ); ?>" />      <input type="hidden" name="instance" value="<?php $template->the_instance(); ?>" />         <input type="hidden" name="action" value="register" />  </p> </form>
```

Code JS form (2):

```
                    case 'select':
                        /*
                         * Select field.
                         */
                        HTML.push('     <div id="DOPBSPCalendar-form-field-warning'+ID+'_'+formField['id']+'" class="dopbsp-warning-info DOPBSPCalendar-hidden">');
                        HTML.push('         <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dopbsp-icon"></a>');
                        HTML.push('         <div class="dopbsp-message">'+formField['translation']+' '+methods_form.text['required']+'</div>');
                        HTML.push('     </div>');
                        HTML.push('     <label for="DOPBSPCalendar-form-field'+ID+'_'+formField['id']+'">'+formField['translation']+(formField['required'] === 'true' ? '  <span class="dopbsp-required">*</span>':'')+'</label>');
                        HTML.push('     <select name="DOPBSPCalendar-form-field'+ID+'_'+formField['id']+(formField['multiple_select'] === 'true' ? '[]':'')+'" id="DOPBSPCalendar-form-field'+ID+'_'+formField['id']+'" value=""'+(formField['multiple_select'] === 'true' ? ' multiple':'')+'>');

                        for (j=0; j<formField['options'].length; j++){
                            formFieldOption = formField['options'][j];
                            HTML.push('<option value="'+formFieldOption['id']+'">'+formFieldOption['translation']+'</option>');
                        }
                        HTML.push('     </select>');
                        break;
                    case 'text':
                        /*
                         * Text field.
                         */
                        HTML.push('     <div id="DOPBSPCalendar-form-field-warning'+ID+'_'+formField['id']+'" class="dopbsp-warning-info DOPBSPCalendar-hidden">');
                        HTML.push('         <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dopbsp-icon"></a>');
                        HTML.push('         <div class="dopbsp-message">'+formField['translation']+' '+(formField['is_email'] === 'true' ? methods_form.text['invalidEmail']:methods_form.text['required'])+'</div>');
                        HTML.push('     </div>');
                        HTML.push('     <label for="DOPBSPCalendar-form-field'+ID+'_'+formField['id']+'">'+formField['translation']+(formField['required'] === 'true' ? ' <span class="dopbsp-required">*</span>':'')+'</label>');
                        HTML.push('     <input type="text" name="DOPBSPCalendar-form-field'+ID+'_'+formField['id']+'" id="DOPBSPCalendar-form-field'+ID+'_'+formField['id']+'" value="" />');
                        break;
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: is it required that you use a plugins only in simple task?

Comment: duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23740548/how-to-pass-variables-and-data-from-php-to-javascript

Comment: @HTTP: Yes, it's necessary. ;)

Comment: Suggest would be to save data in session after first form is submitted and to show it in second form is easy

Comment: @GeorgeGarchagudashvili: I tried this, but the plugin of the second form returns "undefined"... :(

Comment: @SteYeu Sorry I don't get you what you mean? :/